# delay function using clock()

Tags: c, printf, time.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void delay(double sec)
{
    clock_t start = clock();

    while ((clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < sec)
        ;       
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        printf("%d  ", i);
        delay(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote a delay function and tested it with this code, but I didn't see any number in standard output.

Then I changed the printf() call like this :

```
printf("%d \n", i);
```

Interestingly, it worked. I also tried without delay function like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        printf("%d  ", i);
```

It also worked. What am I missing here? Why can't I see any number when I run the first code? Thanks for helps :)

Comment: Why won't you use normal `sleep()` function?

Comment: I can use it, but I asked this because of my curiosity.

Comment: @TimCooper I edited code. It was wrong

Comment: While that is not your main point, I'd like to point out that busy waiting is very bad because it consumes CPU time - at least on multitasking OSes.

Comment: @glglgl What are the alternative ways other than busy waiting? And can you explain why it is bad on multitasking?

Comment: @yunusaydin As others pointed out, `sleep()`. Or something else provided by the OS. This tells the OS not to touch this process for the next time, so no CPU time is consumed for it. On busy waiting, the process gets full CPU time for essentially doing nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the output is buffered. Most terminals will buffer the standard-output until either a newline (`\n`) is encountered, or `fflush(stdout)` is called.

Your loop that includes the call to `delay` should eventually print the numbers, but when the program is finished.

Add `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`-call to make the numbers appear immediately without newlines in between.

Comment: what you said worked. Thank you :) But I have a question. loop with delay does't eventually print numbers. What's the reason?

Comment: Are you sure? `100000` 'seconds' (see Chris J. Kiick's answer about the granularity of `clock`) is quite long (>27 hours), do you let the program finish? My terminal, for some reason, doesn't buffer and I can see the numbers appear immediately though it's going to take quite some time to print them all. Try looping to 100.

Comment: @Kninnug essentially, it would flush buffer not only on \n, but also having standard buffer (e.g. 4KB) filled. But with the poster's approach and this buffer size it will take approx. 1050 seconds = 17.5 minutes - more than enough for a human's patience unless diverted for a dinner:)

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are two reasons.  First, `printf()` doesn't always flush its output, so you may actually get past the `printf` statement and still not see anything on your terminal. The text is buffered. Putting in a `\n` may have caused it to flush its output, so that's why that worked.

The second problem is that you are not passing any value to your `delay()` function.  So it's probably using some random value, and hanging.

I'd also like to point out that `clock()` returns CPU time, not "wall clock" time, so it may actually take longer than you think.

Delay functions are tricky, that's why there are lots of system calls to do them. See `sleep()`.